# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'product' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter, math

I am making a times tables practicing tool that randomly selects two numbers 1-12. I have done this without a GUI and it worked. I am using tkinter now to make it a bit more intuitive. Whenever I type in the entry box and click the "check answer" button, an error comes up saying that the "local variable 'product' has been referenced before assignment". This variable is used to get the answer to the current question by multiplying them.

I was hoping that the program would work, and that when you pressed "check answer" the game would move onto the next question. Here is the code:

```
import random, tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("180x100")

randomNumberOne = random.randint(1,12)
randomNumberTwo = random.randint(1,12)
product = randomNumberOne * randomNumberTwo
points = 0

def check():
    guess = int(entry.get())
    if guess == product:
        randomNumberOne = random.randint(1,12)
        randomNumberTwo = random.randint(1,12)
        product = randomNumberOne * randomNumberTwo
        points += 1
        label.config(text = f"What is {randomNumberOne} times {randomNumberTwo}?")
    if guess != product:
        label.config(text = f"Game over! Points: {points}. Click 'reset' to try again.")

def reset():
    randomNumberOne = random.randint(1,12)
    randomNumberTwo = random.randint(1,12)
    product = randomNumberOne * randomNumberTwo
    points = 0
    label.config(text = f"What is {randomNumberOne} times {randomNumberTwo}?")

label = tkinter.Label(root, text=f"What is {randomNumberOne} times {randomNumberTwo}?")
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button_check = tkinter.Button(root, text="Check answer", command=check)
button_check.pack()

button_reset = tkinter.Button(root, text="Reset game", command=reset)
button_reset.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are using `product` as a global variable. As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: If you must use globals, the function needs to know about it.  Otherwise it assumes the variable is local.  Put `global product` at the top of the function.

Comment: @JohnGordon: ... of *both* functions.

Comment: @quamrana I assumed they would realize that my advice applied to "any and all functions where the variable is used".

Comment: However, there is the gotcha that leaving `def reset()` as is means that the global product won't be written to when the reset button is pressed.

Comment: A function can use a global variable "read-only". For example `x=12` `def f(): print(x)` `f(); print(x)` would print `12` then `12`. But as long as, somewhere in the function you "write" the variable value, then it becomes a local variable. `x=12` `def f(): x=15; print(x)` `f(); print(x)` would print `15` then `12`. Because, inside `f`, `x` is a local variable. And that goes where ever the "write" to `x` occurs. As long as there is one wherever in `f` code, then, `f`'s `x` is a local `x`. So in `def f(): print(x); x=15`  `x` is also a local `x` everywhere in `f`'s code.

Comment: So, in that last example, `x=12` `def f(): print(x); x=15` `f(); print(x)` would raise an error. Because `f`'s `x` is a local x. Including in `print(x)` line. But that local `x` hasn't yet been assigned. So it is a reference before assignment of a variable. Hence the error.

Comment: But, still, you can force a variable to be the global one, even when it is locally assigned, with the keyword `global`. `x=12` `def f(): global x; print(x); x=15` `f(); print(x)` would print `12` then `15`, because inside `f`'s code, both `print(x)` and `x=15` lines are about global `x` (there is no `x` local to `f` here).

Comment: So, main point to keep in mind: inside a code function, a given name is always the same variable. Inside `f`'s code, `x` always designates the same thing. Either it designates a local variable named `x`, or it designates a global variable named `x`. But it can't be both. It can't change during execution (and even between different executions). That is a "static" consideration (as "static" things can be in an interpreted language): as soon as the interpreter loaded the `.py` file and read the code, it is decided once for all whether `x` in `f` function is a local or global `x`.

Comment: And that decision is made by looking if there is a `global` declaration, and if there is a assignment (in absence of `global` declaration, it is global if there isn't any assignment, and local if there is). In your code function `check`'s variable `product` is local since `check` contains an assignment of `product`. And it is unassigned the first time the line `if guess==product` is reached. Hence the error.

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: Bad programming notwithstanding, at its core this is basically a duplicate of [How to use a global variable in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/how-to-use-a-global-variable-in-a-function).

Answer (score -2):

Create a separate function for asking question alone. And Call this function in other two functions as and when required. Make the variables `points, product` as global variables

```
import random, tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("180x100")

randomNumberOne = random.randint(1,12)
randomNumberTwo = random.randint(1,12)
product = randomNumberOne * randomNumberTwo
points = 0


def question():
    global product
    randomNumberOne = random.randint(1,12)
    randomNumberTwo = random.randint(1,12)
    product = randomNumberOne * randomNumberTwo
    label.config(text = f"What is {randomNumberOne} times {randomNumberTwo}?")
    

def check():
    global product, points
    guess = int(entry.get())
    if guess == product:
        points += 1
        question()
    else:
        label.config(text = f"Game over! Points: {points}. Click 'reset' to try again.")

def reset():
    global points, product
    
    question()
    points = 0
    

label = tkinter.Label(root, text=f"What is {randomNumberOne} times {randomNumberTwo}?")
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button_check = tkinter.Button(root, text="Check answer", command=check)
button_check.pack()

button_reset = tkinter.Button(root, text="Reset game", command=reset)
button_reset.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I had posted a similar program of mine with more features. This contains a complete program except styling. You can copy and paste to your test editor and check step by step for easy understanding.
[Check My program with more features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734371/22577409)

Comment: Why my answer has been downloaded? After correcting I tested whether it was working. After confirming only I posted. The OP's algorithm is as follows: For every correct answer point will be added but will not be shown. If there is a single wrong answer, it will prompt,"Game is over. And your score is <total score">